# How to pass Generic Interface T to function with class reference as parameter

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have a Generic Interface for retrofit2 http request

```
interface BaseGetRequest<T: Any>  {
@GET fun requestGet(@Url urlGetRequest: String,@FieldMap parameters: Map<String, String>): Single<T>
}
```

and now I need to pass the BaseGetRequest to retrofit2 as class reference, in java this is just treated as BaseGetRequest.java, but does not allow in kotlin because it says type mismatch.

[image]

Create[image]

How do I solve this?

Comment: show create method of NetworkUtils.builder

Comment: @AndreyDanilov I updated my question. It actually work if I dont used generic interface but I just wanted to used generic so I wont have to write a interface request again for my other http request.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake the create in retrofit2

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should return type that you want to get as response.

If you do not need result I would recommend to use `Completable` instead of `Single`.

But if you need single guess you can write just:

```
NetworkUtils.builder().create(BaseRequest::class.java)
```

without any diamond operator

Comment: So retrofit requires you to return a type ? I guess Iv rather used JsonElement then and serialized or convert from json to class or model somewhere in my CallBack.